# Monitor CPU and memory consumption of a specific processes in (Windows) C?

Tags: c, windows, memory-management, cpu-usage

i would like to monitor the cpu and memory consumption of a given process in windows (nt architecture - xp,vista,win7), every few seconds to make a graph
i have searched around but found only non C solutions only (java,c#,c++, etc)
i know there is a PerformanceCounter class, but obviously it is not available in c.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Win32 Performance Counters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> **Developer Audience:**
>
> Performance Counters is designed for use by C and
>   C++ developers.

However, If you just want a tool to show you this information, get Mark Russinovich's [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). It can show per-process stats and graphs.

Comment: i already know of that tool. i also specified i need to do this from code

Comment: @moveaxebx: In that case use performance counters. They are NOT C++ only.